# Python pefile Write failure

Tags: python, windows

Fails on machine 1 but not on other machine.s The files are all hosted on machine 1 on a shared drive.

```
import sys
import pefile

pe = pefile.PE(sys.argv[1])
pe.write (sys.argv[1])
print "Finished!"
```

It fails on machine 1 with

```
 pe.write (sys.argv[1])
  File "n:\Python27\pefile.py", line 2155, in write
    f = file(filename, 'wb+')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb+') or filename: 'notepad.exe'
```

(excerpt form pefile

```
            f = file(filename, 'wb+')
            f.write(new_file_data)
            f.close()
```

)

(but this works fine

```
f = file(sys.argv[1], 'wb+')
f.write("Hello World")
f.close()
```

)

Admitted this may not be a Python issue, I'm a bit stumped.
The host machine is Windows Server 2016, client machines are Win 8 and Win 10 pro.
I've tried a few different exes.

Edit -
I retargetted this at Python 3.10 with the same result, except the error is slightly different

```
  File "n:\python310\lib\site-packages\pefile.py", line 3325, in write
    f = open(filename, "wb+")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'notepad.exe'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Looks like you're trying to modify notepad.exe

Comment: This is a snippet of some legacy code. The point of it is to change the version number of an exe - I've stripped it back to it's bare essentials here!

Comment: Did you try with the full path? Also note that you have to be an administrator in order to write "system" files.

Comment: Yes, I'm comparing the behaviour of the host system (that fails) and a client (my PC) for the same folder, same target executable. I've dumped it all into a test folder. It does run from a non-admin shell OK, but it does look like a permissions issue doesn't it?